# Chinese char* conversion to NSString on iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, character-encoding, nsstring

I'd like to convert GB encoded `char *` to `NSString *`:

```
char *str = ...
size_t len = ...

NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:str length:len encoding:???];
```

`encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` is available. I wonder it there an predefined encoding for GB Chinese characters? similar to [kCFStringEncodingGB_2312_80](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html), defined in `CFStringEncoding`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CF string encodings with NSString; from [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstringencoding):

> Additional encodings are defined in [String Programming Guide for Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/introCFStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000131i) (see CFStringEncodingExt.h); these encodings can be used with NSString by first passing the Core Foundation encoding to the [`CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1543046-cfstringconvertencodingtonsstrin?language=objc) function.

Answer (score 0):

Because NSString And CFString are toll-free bridged, you can simply cast from one to the other:

```
NSString *str = (__bridge __strong NSString *) CFStringCreateWithBytes(NULL, str, length, kCFStringEncodingGB_2312_80, NO);
```

Comment: I don't believe this is valid objective-c.  I think the keyword you want is (__bridge_transfer NSString *).  If I am wrong though, feel free to correct me.